# Comprobar si un INSERT de Sentencias Preparadas se ha realizado con éxito en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, prepared-statements

Mi sitio web realiza un **MySQLi** `INSERT` usando las **Sentencias Preparadas** (Prepared Statements) y quiero comprobar *si se ha insertado con éxito o no*, porque dependiendo de eso, hago una re-dirección o muestro un error.

*Mi código (Por si sirve de algo):*

```
//CONEXIÓN CON LA BASE DE DATOS
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "tiny***e", "097GFPer*******", "tiny***e");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    array_push($errors,"Hubo un problema al intentar conectar con el servidor");
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO links (UID, title, url, yt, video) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $UID, $title, $url, $yt, $video);
$stmt->execute();
```

Antes no usaba las sentencias preparadas y me servía con esto, y quiero algo con lo que pueda hacer lo mismo:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: /?v=' . $UID);
} else {
    /echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    array_push($errors,"Error al crear el enlace. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9991935/6999690) del sitio gringo, y tal como pensaba, [execute regresa un booleano](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) para indicar si funcionó o no.

```
if ($stmt->execute()) { 
   // funcionó
   header('Location: /?v=' . $UID);
} else {
   // chafeó :C
}
```

Comment: Realmente lo correcto para probar si un `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` funcionaron, sería usando [`affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php). El que `execute` devuelva `TRUE` no es necesariamente indicativo de que hubo una inserción. Llegados a este punto, sería interesante saber qué devuelve `execute` si la inserción viola alguna restricción por ejemplo. Si devuelve `true`, el código que propones asumirá que hubo una inserción. Como ese caso pueden haber otros que se escapan, por tanto una prueba del resultado de `execute` no es lo más seguro.

Comment: @A.Cedano concuerdo en que la pregunta es ambigua, y estaría de acuerdo contigo si hubiera preguntado "cómo compruebo que se ha insertado en la base de datos" y desafortunadamente no conozco algún framework de testing de base de datos para PHP como en Java lo es DBUnit, además de que no estoy seguro de que satisfaga la necesidad de la persona que pregunta. De momento asumimos que la pregunta es un "como compruebo sin tener acceso a la base de datos"

Comment: El OP pregunta sobre cómo verificar si la inserción ha sido efectiva. Yo entiendo por eso: *verificar si realmente hubo una inserción o el código falló por cualquier causa*. Para salir de la curiosidad hice pruebas con una consulta que violaría una restricción `UNIQUE` y efectivamente en ese caso `execute` devolvería `FALSE`, con lo cual sería válido para hacer la comprobación. Aunque sigo pensando que una comprobación con `affected_rows` sea quizá más específica. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo de varias formas:

```
 1. if ($stmt->execute()){ // se ejecuto correctamente}
 2. if($conn->affected_rows > 0){ //una fila afectada se ejecuto correctamente}
 3. if($stmt->insert_id){ // se ejecuto, se inserto un nuevo id
```

tambien puedes ver la info de la ejecucion con:

```
$conn->info()
```

Answer (score 0):

También lo puedes hacer así:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "tiny***e", "097GFPer*******", "tiny***e");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    array_push($errors,"Hubo un problema al intentar conectar con el servidor");
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO links (UID, title, url, yt, video) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$ok = $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $UID, $title, $url, $yt, $video);
$ok = $stmt->execute();
if($ok==1){
   echo "consulta ejecutada correctamente";
}
```